# Getting a double quote after saving a dataframe in csv format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one column. It contains json request in each row.
While I save the dataframe into a csv format I see double quotes around each json request.
I am not sure why is this happening. Is there a parameter in `to_csv()` I am missing.
My dataframe :

```
0   {"items":[{"depth":26.5,"height":10.0,"width":20.0,"item_cd":"4562166805883","item_name":"やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SPINKR4562166805883","qty":2}],"order_cd":"5034868310","seller_cd":"31056"}
1   {"items":[{"depth":26.5,"height":10.0,"width":20.0,"item_cd":"4562166805883","item_name":"やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SPINKR4562166805883","qty":1},{"depth":26.5,"height":10.0,"width":20.0,"item_cd":"4562166805890","item_name":"やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SBLUER4562166805890","qty":1}],"order_cd":"5034868317","seller_cd":"31056"}
2   {"items":[{"depth":27.4,"height":3.1,"width":21.5,"item_cd":"2400000071440","item_name":"子ども用カットソー【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチ長袖Tシャツトップスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-5047-K110-061-MGR","qty":1},{"depth":34.0,"height":2.0,"width":13.0,"item_cd":"2400000070948","item_name":"子ども用パンツ【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチパンツボトムスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-2012-K120-061-MGR","qty":1},{"depth":26.0,"height":3.5,"width":21.3,"item_cd":"2400000071563","item_name":"子ども用カットソー【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチ長袖Tシャツトップスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-5047-K130-001-WT","qty":1},{"depth":33.1,"height":3.5,"width":28.5,"item_cd":"2400000073468","item_name":"【OMNESAnotherEdition】ベアワッフルヘンリーネックトップスレディースカットソーフリーサイズ半袖カジュアルトップスボタンHAPTICハプティック母の日7120-5055-F-031-GBG","qty":1}],"order_cd":"5034867576","seller_cd":"32424"}
3   {"items":[{"depth":12.4,"height":9.5,"width":23.8,"item_cd":"4580294612012","item_name":"競技用けん玉「大空」単色：青R4580294612012","qty":20}],"order_cd":"5034868288","seller_cd":"31056"}
4   {"items":[{"depth":29.1,"height":10.7,"width":31.2,"item_cd":"2400000056799","item_name":"キッズレインブーツスノーブーツキッズジュニア長靴OMNES13cm14cm15cm16cm17cm18cm19cm20cm21cm22cm北欧カラー女の子男の子1519-3001-210-004-GY","qty":1},{"depth":21.6,"height":3.6,"width":28.9,"item_cd":"2400000108719","item_name":"OMNESユニセックス製品洗い無地長袖Tシャツレディースメンズカジュアルトップスシンプルベーシック1521-5111-7-001-WT","qty":1}],"order_cd":"5034867578","seller_cd":"32424"}
```

csv file output I am getting is as :

```
"{""items"":[{""depth"":26.5,""height"":10.0,""width"":20.0,""item_cd"":""4562166805883"",""item_name"":""やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SPINKR4562166805883"",""qty"":2}],""order_cd"":""5034868310"",""seller_cd"":""31056""}"
"{""items"":[{""depth"":26.5,""height"":10.0,""width"":20.0,""item_cd"":""4562166805883"",""item_name"":""やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SPINKR4562166805883"",""qty"":1},{""depth"":26.5,""height"":10.0,""width"":20.0,""item_cd"":""4562166805890"",""item_name"":""やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SBLUER4562166805890"",""qty"":1}],""order_cd"":""5034868317"",""seller_cd"":""31056""}"
"{""items"":[{""depth"":27.4,""height"":3.1,""width"":21.5,""item_cd"":""2400000071440"",""item_name"":""子ども用カットソー【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチ長袖Tシャツトップスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-5047-K110-061-MGR"",""qty"":1},{""depth"":34.0,""height"":2.0,""width"":13.0,""item_cd"":""2400000070948"",""item_name"":""子ども用パンツ【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチパンツボトムスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-2012-K120-061-MGR"",""qty"":1},{""depth"":26.0,""height"":3.5,""width"":21.3,""item_cd"":""2400000071563"",""item_name"":""子ども用カットソー【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチ長袖Tシャツトップスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-5047-K130-001-WT"",""qty"":1},{""depth"":33.1,""height"":3.5,""width"":28.5,""item_cd"":""2400000073468"",""item_name"":""【OMNESAnotherEdition】ベアワッフルヘンリーネックトップスレディースカットソーフリーサイズ半袖カジュアルトップスボタンHAPTICハプティック母の日7120-5055-F-031-GBG"",""qty"":1}],""order_cd"":""5034867576"",""seller_cd"":""32424""}"
"{""items"":[{""depth"":12.4,""height"":9.5,""width"":23.8,""item_cd"":""4580294612012"",""item_name"":""競技用けん玉「大空」単色：青R4580294612012"",""qty"":20}],""order_cd"":""5034868288"",""seller_cd"":""31056""}"
```

I am not sure why there are `""` in the `csv` file.

Code that I have used to get the csv file:

```
df.to_csv("sample.csv",header=None, index=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While **@Daweo**'s answer explains why you are getting double-quotes in your csv, in order to avoid them you need to make use of `sep`, `quoting` and `escapechar` params in **`to_csv()`** method.

Since you have only one column in your df, you can do it as below:

```
df.to_csv("sample.csv",header=None, index=None, sep='\t', quoting=3, escapechar=' ')
```

**sample.csv:**

```
{"items":[{"depth":26.5,"height":10.0,"width":20.0,"item_cd":"4562166805883","item_name":"やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SPINKR4562166805883","qty":2}],"order_cd":"5034868310","seller_cd":"31056"}
{"items":[{"depth":26.5,"height":10.0,"width":20.0,"item_cd":"4562166805883","item_name":"やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SPINKR4562166805883","qty":1},{"depth":26.5,"height":10.0,"width":20.0,"item_cd":"4562166805890","item_name":"やわらかエコ湯たんぽプレミアムCY-N10SBLUER4562166805890","qty":1}],"order_cd":"5034868317","seller_cd":"31056"}
{"items":[{"depth":27.4,"height":3.1,"width":21.5,"item_cd":"2400000071440","item_name":"子ども用カットソー【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチ長袖Tシャツトップスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-5047-K110-061-MGR","qty":1},{"depth":34.0,"height":2.0,"width":13.0,"item_cd":"2400000070948","item_name":"子ども用パンツ【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチパンツボトムスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-2012-K120-061-MGR","qty":1},{"depth":26.0,"height":3.5,"width":21.3,"item_cd":"2400000071563","item_name":"子ども用カットソー【OMNES】キッズジャガードストレッチ長袖Tシャツトップスカジュアルこども用80cm90cm100cm110cm120cm130cm140cmHAPTICハプティック母の日1519-5047-K130-001-WT","qty":1},{"depth":33.1,"height":3.5,"width":28.5,"item_cd":"2400000073468","item_name":"【OMNESAnotherEdition】ベアワッフルヘンリーネックトップスレディースカットソーフリーサイズ半袖カジュアルトップスボタンHAPTICハプティック母の日7120-5055-F-031-GBG","qty":1}],"order_cd":"5034867576","seller_cd":"32424"}
{"items":[{"depth":12.4,"height":9.5,"width":23.8,"item_cd":"4580294612012","item_name":"競技用けん玉「大空」単色：青R4580294612012","qty":20}],"order_cd":"5034868288","seller_cd":"31056"}
{"items":[{"depth":29.1,"height":10.7,"width":31.2,"item_cd":"2400000056799","item_name":"キッズレインブーツスノーブーツキッズジュニア長靴OMNES13cm14cm15cm16cm17cm18cm19cm20cm21cm22cm北欧カラー女の子男の子1519-3001-210-004-GY","qty":1},{"depth":21.6,"height":3.6,"width":28.9,"item_cd":"2400000108719","item_name":"OMNESユニセックス製品洗い無地長袖Tシャツレディースメンズカジュアルトップスシンプルベーシック1521-5111-7-001-WT","qty":1}],"order_cd":"5034867578","seller_cd":"32424"}
```

Answer (score 1):

*I am not sure why is this happening*

According to [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)

```
   7.  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
       appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote.  For example:

       "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
```